# How are the checksums in go.sum computed?

Tags: go, checksum, go-modules

I looked at https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref and https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy, and on neither page could I find any documentation that explains how the checksums in `go.sum` are computed.

How are the checksums in `go.sum` computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checksums are hashes of the dependencies. The document you look for is https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-sum-files.

> Each line in go.sum has three fields separated by spaces: a module path, a version (possibly ending with /go.mod), and a hash.
>
> - The module path is the name of the module the hash belongs to.
> - The version is the version of the module the hash belongs to. If the version ends with /go.mod, the hash is for the module’s go.mod file only; otherwise, the hash is for the files within the module’s .zip file.
> - The hash column consists of an algorithm name (like h1) and a base64-encoded cryptographic hash, separated by a colon (:). Currently, SHA-256 (h1) is the only supported hash algorithm. If a vulnerability in SHA-256 is discovered in the future, support will be added for another algorithm (named h2 and so on).

Example go.sum line with `module version hash` is like

```
github.com/go-chi/chi v1.5.4 h1:QHdzF2szwjqVV4wmByUnTcsbIg7UGaQ0tPF2t5GcAIs=
github.com/go-chi/chi v1.5.4/go.mod h1:uaf8YgoFazUOkPBG7fxPftUylNumIev9awIWOENIuEg=
```

Comment: What is the hash a hash of? Is it a hash of just the `go.mod` file? Or is it a hash of the full package (i.e., including every file in the package)?

Comment: It seems the package's hash can't be a hash of the `go.mod` file, since the `go.mod` base64-encoded hash in your example does not match the package's base64-encoded hash.

Comment: @ShaneBishop it is said in point two of the document I quoted: If the version ends with /go.mod, the hash is for the module’s go.mod file only; otherwise, the hash is for the files within the module’s .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in calculating/verifying `checksums` manually you could check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579470/3405980).

With `bash` by passing the `cache`, `prefix` of downloaded modules:

```
 harsha $ sha256sum $(find /Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0 -type f | sort ) | sed 's#/Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/##' | sha256sum | xxd -r -p | base64       
 CM0HF96J0hcLAwsHPJZjfdNzs0gftsLfgKt57wWHJ0o=
```

With `go` using inbuilt `HashDir` function defined [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.12.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=70-79):

```
func TestHashDir2(t *testing.T) {
  out, err := HashDir("/Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0", "golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0", Hash1)
  if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("HashDir: %v", err)
  }

  want := "h1:CM0HF96J0hcLAwsHPJZjfdNzs0gftsLfgKt57wWHJ0o="
  if out != want {
    t.Errorf("HashDir(...) = %s, want %s", out, want)
  }
}
```