# How to manually generate sha256 checksum to match with entry in go.sum?

Tags: go, checksum

```
github.com/foo/bar v0.0.0-20231129062549-b7ab892f9094 h1:mLLR/caPeDkssu3k//uDZs9mh3SDpgPvecIqilAQgss=
github.com/foo/bar v0.0.0-20231129062549-b7ab892f9094/go.mod h1:UZLHFxCzQiKhdNMV45+uMSq4pDYoiEycD23VZdOo4aw=
```

I'm trying to manually generate both the value `h1:mLLR/caPeDkssu3k//uDZs9mh3SDpgPvecIqilAQgss=` & `h1:UZLHFxCzQiKhdNMV45+uMSq4pDYoiEycD23VZdOo4aw=` but so far failed to do it.

First attempt:

```bash
find ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/foo/bar@v0.0.0-20231129062549-b7ab892f9094/ -type f -exec cat {} + | sha256sum

864c5090b6443e61a7ff1c84c2e5aed65d7d2d6bece73fdec836a864507c8bb9
```

Second attempt:

```golang
func testMD5() {
f, err := os.Open("/Users/xxx/go/pkg/mod/github.com/foo/bar@v0.0.0-20231129062549-b7ab892f9094/puppy.go")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer f.Close()

  h := sha256.New()
  if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}

6ed0f6e4e9a60ab1e9331b8c2baa434c00661df0fa4ac2e487a2052b5cc9ff76
```

My intention is to understand what are the hash value corresponding to and if it's solely based on the content of the file, there should be a way to manually generate them that yield the exact same value

Comment: The values you try to get are base64 encoded but you encode with hex - so you never will get exactly the same string no matter what your input is. You need to use the same encoding.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, I've been trying from sometime to generate the checksums manually but unsuccessful! `echo "<shasum-of-file>" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | base64` doesn't match the one in go.sum. I suspect `xxd -r -p` could be incorrect but don't know what's the right argument I need to pass, tried several options but didn't work.

Comment: In addition to this I do find `"Hash": "something"` with `go list -m -json <module-name>` doesn't match that one either if I use that has an hash with `echo "something" | xxd -r -p | base64`

Comment: As with most internal implementation details, the source will be the reference https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.14.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=44

Comment: Hi @JimB, I was looking at this module as well. But couldn't match the checksum. Also the thing which is bit confusing with docs is that `where each line consists of
// the hexadecimal SHA-256 hash of the file content,
// two spaces (U+0020), the file name, and a newline`. The hash is different when I append `/` to the directory. Another thing I am not sure is to whether convert the `sha256` hash into binary  before encoding with `base64`. Otherwise the encoded string would be much longer than the hash..

Comment: @harshavmb, copy the exact code you see there (and read the doc comment for context). I took the function and it matches the `go.mod` file output exactly.

Comment: @JimB, I did try that as well. Just to clarify I think you are mentioning the checksums stored in `go.sum` file right? Or generating the checksum of `go.mod` file only? I do see both module directory as well as `go.mod` but none of them are matching with the one in `go.sum` file. Tried bash & python & golang with exactly same function, using the go.mod file.. it is different

Comment: I'll share the code on pastebin from my personal PC as my corporate proxy blocks it..

Comment: @JimB, https://pastebin.com/vFvKHxs5 is the code I tried with..

Comment: @harshavmb: your example is hashing `"File content for " + file`, which is not the content of the `go.mod` file in question. If you change `open` to `os.Open` you get the same hash.

Comment: Hi @JimB, thanks for your time & correcting the code. Nevertheless, I'm unable to grasp how to get it done. I got a simplified code here :: https://pastebin.com/7TbpJwcW 
It returns the base64 encoding of the hash of the go.mod file in above example but it neither matches the one in `go.mod` nor with my bash command `shasum -a 256 $(find /Users/harshavmb/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.11.0/go.mod -type f | sort) | shasum -a 256 | x
xd -r -p | base64`. I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I want the hash to be matched to `h1:oPkhp1MJrh7nUepCBck5+mAzfO9JrbApNNgaTdGDITg=`

Comment: a self contained example with that go.mod file inline: https://go.dev/play/p/UJ-o3AHcJqP

Comment: Thanks @JimB. Now I realize the mistake I made with the go program. your help is much appreciated! I'll try to find the relevant `bash` command to match it as well. Once again, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't knowing until yesterday but I spent sometime on this to find out how to calculate checksums for go modules.

Thanks to @JimB who helped a lot in the chat with `go.mod` file. I took inspiration from that & found how to calculate `checksums` for modules too.

I found the way it works is ::

- Calculate the sha256sum of each file content in the module directory
- format the above calculated sha2sum followed by two spaces, filename and the new line (`fmt.Fprintf(h, "%x  %s\n", hf.Sum(nil), file)`. It's taken from [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.12.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=62)
- Now calculate the `sha256sum` for all the files together
- Convert above `hex` output into binary mode with `xxd` (on *unix systems, if you do programmatically, `base64` could be encoded directly from `byte array`)
- Encode it with `base64`
- Compare the output with `checksum` in `go.sum` file

For `go.mod` file it's relatively easy to calculate with below `bash` command ::

```
harsha$ sha256sum $(find go.mod -type f | sort) | sha256sum | xxd -r -p | base64
oPkhp1MJrh7nUepCBck5+mAzfO9JrbApNNgaTdGDITg=
```

This matches the `checksum` defined in `go.sum` file using `golang.org/x/sys` module `v0.12.0` version.

Only thing one needs to be aware is the path of the `go.mod` shouldn't be passed as it can also influence the `sha256sum` calculation in 2nd iteration.

For `module` directory verification, the process is almost same except the `file` name as `go` verifies it bit differently compared to `go.mod`. From [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a27a525d1b4df74989ac9f6ad10394391fe3eb88/src/cmd/go/internal/modcmd/verify.go#L129C1-L129C81), to calculate the `hash` of directory followed by prefix of the module path like `mod.Path+"@"+mod.Version` which translates to `golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0` for `sys` module.

```
 harsha $ sha256sum $(find /Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0 -type f | sort ) | sed 's#/Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/##' | sha256sum | xxd -r -p | base64       
 CM0HF96J0hcLAwsHPJZjfdNzs0gftsLfgKt57wWHJ0o=
```

The `sed` here trims `filepath` from absolute path `/Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0` to `golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0` (mod path)

I could verify the same with `golang` too by targeting `HashDir` function [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.12.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=70-79)

```
func TestHashDir2(t *testing.T) {
  out, err := HashDir("/Users/hmusanalli/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0", "golang.org/x/sys@v0.12.0", Hash1)
  if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("HashDir: %v", err)
  }

  want := "h1:CM0HF96J0hcLAwsHPJZjfdNzs0gftsLfgKt57wWHJ0o="
  if out != want {
    t.Errorf("HashDir(...) = %s, want %s", out, want)
  }
}
```

Go Documentation [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.12.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=31-43) is very clear except on how to find the `prefix` to calculate `HashDir`