# How can I check go.mod hash from sum.golang.org with Python?

Tags: python, go, hash

I need to verify hashes for go.mod files provided by sum.golang.org. I need to use PYTHON.

For example - https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.2 for file https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/@v/v1.6.2.mod

Here we are:

```
import base64
import requests
import hashlib
import os

# some tmp file
tmp_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/tmp.mod'

# url for sumdb
link_sum_db = 'https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.2'
# our line:
# github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.2/go.mod h1:75u5sXoLsGZoRN5Sgbi1eraJ4GU3++wFwWzhwvtwp4M=
hash_from_sumdb = b'75u5sXoLsGZoRN5Sgbi1eraJ4GU3++wFwWzhwvtwp4M='
print(hash_from_sumdb)
# b'75u5sXoLsGZoRN5Sgbi1eraJ4GU3++wFwWzhwvtwp4M='

# download the file
f_url = 'https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/@v/v1.6.2.mod'
f_url_content = requests.get(f_url).content
with open(tmp_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(f_url_content)

with open(tmp_file, 'rb') as f:
    f_file_content = f.read()

# calculate hash from local tmp file
hash_from_file = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(f_file_content).digest())
print(hash_from_file)
# b'x9T1RkIbnNSJydQMU9l8mvXfhBIkDhO3TTHCbOVG4Go='
# and it fails =(
assert hash_from_file == hash_from_sumdb
```

Please, help me. I know about `go` command, but I need to use python here...
I've read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234905/how-are-the-checksums-in-go-sum-computed) , but it didn't help =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bit more involved than that.
I followed the topic you mentioned and found more details on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569122/how-to-manually-generate-sha256-checksum-to-match-with-entry-in-go-sum/77579470#77579470).
Also, if you refer to [this function's source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.14.0:sumdb/dirhash/hash.go;l=44), you can see how the hash used in go modules is implemented.

This version works:

```
import hashlib
import base64

def calculate_sha256_checksum(data):
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
    sha256_hash.update(data.encode('utf-8'))
    return sha256_hash.digest()

# Specify the file path
file_path = 'go.mod'

# Read the file content
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    file_content = file.read()

# Calculate the SHA256 checksum of the file content
checksum1 = calculate_sha256_checksum(file_content)

# Format the checksum followed by two spaces, filename, and a new line
formatted_string = f'{checksum1.hex()}  {file_path}\n'

# Calculate the SHA256 checksum of the formatted string
checksum2 = calculate_sha256_checksum(formatted_string)

# Convert the checksum to base64
base64_checksum = base64.b64encode(checksum2).decode('utf-8')

print(base64_checksum)
```